# mPDF error: Could not find image file

Tags: centos, mpdf, hosts

When generating a PDF using `mpdf` I get the error:

> mPDF error: IMAGE Error (https://mywebsite.com/images/foo.png): Could not find image file

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514062/mpdf-not-rendering-images-mpdf-error-image-error-could-not-find-image-file) says that its a internal domain resolution error. I know its an internal server domain resolution issue because if I place that above image url into my browser the image appears.

So I have done the advice in the above post and added my domain to `/etc/hosts` but it still doesn't work.

What do I need to configure on my Cent OS 6.8 VPS to resolve these urls internally? Maybe I need to restart some services on the server to enable the change?. My server is with GoDaddy and all of the below was already in the file. I just added `mywebsite.com` to `127.0.0.1`.

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost mywebsite.com
::1             localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
XX.XX.XXX.222           mywebsite.com sXXX-XXX-XX-71.secureserver.net sXXX-XXX-XX-71 ip-XX-XX-XXX-222.ip.secureserver.net ip-XX-XX-XXX-222
XXX.XXX.XX.71           mywebsite.com
```

**For context;** The PDF is built from a HTML template that has images in it. The image urls are in the format `src="/images/foo.png"`.

Comment: Did u found the answer ?

Answer (score 3):

use src="image/foo.png" instead of src="/image/foo.png" helped me